# Cmake : causing non existent errors

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, codeblocks

In  my C project I have 4-5 files. First I tested them by directly including source files in include section.
I used codeblocks to do it.My program ran perefectly fine.

But problem came when I tried to build project using Cmake.
I specified generator for project as `MingW Makefiles` and ticked "`Use default native compiler`".
Configuring and Generating gets done.

When I run using command `mingw32-make` I get error

```
error: too few arguments to function 'strnlen'
 int len=strnlen(buf);
```

I have included string.h still error is alive. These error were never showed up when I run directly in codeblocks. I tried changing compiler to compilers in folder of codeblocks. Sill no use.
Any suggestion like which compiler I should  to make it work? Idk where codeblocks default compiler location is..

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation of this functon? Such as [`man 3 strnlen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strnlen.3.html) ?

Comment: This function does not seem to be defined in [`string.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) according to the standard (at lease as represented by cppreference.com). All the `strnlen` functions I found require 2 parameters. Not sure where codeblocks gets this function, but you cannot rely on this function being available for other compilers...

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with cmake or codeblocks. Your code is wrong. `strnlen` requires two arguments. The code compiled (and likely would crash if you had run it) before, simply because in C you can do stupid things like use a function that was never declared, and C will "helpfully" (not!) declare the function for you.

So, in the code that did compile, the compiler "helpfully" added an implicit declaration as follows:

```
int strnlen(...);
// in C this means exactly the same as
int strnlen(); // a function returning int and taking any number of arguments (!)
```

The problem is then that this is not a correct definition of this function, and the program had undefined behavior and may crash, or it may appear to work, and will break when you least expect it to (usually during a demonstration or it won't work for your professor if this was homework assignment).

You'd need to figure out what header to use for that particular function to become available. On Linux and Windows that would be `string.h`, but it's not always present on Windows (e.g. some compilers may not provide that function in their headers or runtime library).